# Recommendations for website/journal/magazine in applied mathematics

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, applications

Which website/journal/magazine would you recommend to keep up with advances in applied mathematics?
More specifically my interest are:

- multivariate/spatial interpolation
- numerical methods
- computational geometry
- geostatistics
- etc

I am looking for a fairly high-level and broad ranging source of info.

Comment: Journal of Applied and Industrial Mathematics - http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/11754

Comment: Journal of Mathematics in Industry - http://www.mathematicsinindustry.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [SIAM Review](http://www.siam.org/journals/sirev.php). It features Survey and Review papers of wide interest.

Answer (score 2):

For multivariate/spatial interpolation (I'm interested in RBFs and meshfree methods), I see things published in SIAM Journal of Numerical Analysis, Mathematics of Computation (Math. Comp), Foundations of Computational Mathematics (FoCM), Constructive Approximation, and Journal of Approximation Theory.